# How can I save Selenium/Selenese tests as .json files?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, nightwatch.js

How can I store a Selenium test in a .json file?

I would like to store Selenium tests as a logic-less .json file.  Selenium IDE allows tests to be saved as .html file (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#selenium-commands-selenese), which is logic-less, but I really prefer to have data like this stored in a json file.  Json makes it easier to work with test-runners like Nightwatch.js.

I do not want tests to be stored in .js, Java, Python, C#, Ruby formats.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Sauce Labs has developed a json format with its Selenium Builder: https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/wiki/JSON-Format